# NetCore 2.0 Couldnot Restore By Using Internal NuGet Source

Tags: .net, nuget, restore

While using NetCore2.0, I create an internal Nuget Server. It can run successfully on IE, and we can see the packages on it.

[image]

Step one
I can find the packages on internal NuGet Server by Adding source on VS（ Win10+Vs2017）and using the Dll successful.

Step two
Copy the project which creates on Step One to another computer(which only install NetCore 2.0 SDK, I tried on WinServer2008 and Mac os 10.12.6), add the source on NuGet.config

```
<add key="nuget.my" value="http://172.19.141.68:8000/nuget/Packages"  />
```

then run DotNet restore command on terminal, and it failed to restore.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer!

The default version of parser is version 3. But my NuGet Server is version 2. So we need pecifiy the parsering version.
Change the config as below:

```
< add key="nuget.myget" value="http://172.19.141.68:8000/nuget/Packages" protocolVersion="2" />
```

Then do restore. It run successfully.